# mysql, multiple table Joins with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, join

I'm using Mysql and I difficult time trying to get the results from a SELECT query. I am having 2 tables. First table jam and second table jadwalblok. data in this table is static:

```
select * from jam
idjam nmjam
01    09.00-09.50
02    10.00-10.50
03    11.00-11.50
04    12.00-13.00   

select * from jadwalblok
idjadwal idjam ruang tgl
1        01    601   2017-04-24
2        03    602   2017-04-25
```

I used joins to get results as.

```
SELECT jam.idjam,
       jam.nmjam,
       jadwalblok.idruang,
       jadwalblok.tgl
FROM jam
LEFT JOIN jadwalblok ON jadwalblok.idjam = jam.idjam
WHERE jadwalblok.tgl='2017-04-24'
```

But I am not getting correct result. I want results as shown below:

```
idjam nmjam        ruang tgl
01    09.00-09.50  601   2017-04-24
02    10.00-10.50  null  null
03    11.00-11.50  null  null
04    12.00-13.00  null  null
```

Comment: Next time pls show the results you get when you run your query, that's a huge help. In this particular case I could determine what had gone wrong, but this may not be the case for a more complicated query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `jadwalblok.tgl='2017-04-24'` criterion from the `where` clause to the join condition because the `where` clause is applied after the 2 tables are joined, while the join condition is applied during the join:

```
SELECT jam.idjam,
       jam.nmjam,
       jadwalblok.idruang,
       jadwalblok.tgl
FROM jam
LEFT JOIN jadwalblok ON jadwalblok.idjam = jam.idjam and jadwalblok.tgl='2017-04-24'
```